WebRTC ICE Connection Fails with "Consent to send expired"
I'm working on a project where I need to establish a WebRTC connection between a C# WPF client (using .NET Core) and a Python FastAPI server. The goal is to have a unidirectional video stream from the server to the client.
The server uses aiortc to stream a synthetic video feed, and the client is built with SIPSorcery to receive the stream. However, after the initial ICE candidate exchange and SDP answer, I consistently see the connection fail with "Consent to send expired" on the server side after a while and the client immediately changing the connection state changed to failed
Minimal reproducible examples
Client Code:
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.WebSockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SIPSorcery.Net;
using SIPSorceryMedia.Encoders;
using SIPSorcery.Media;

namespace Iris.Services
{
    public class IPCameraService
    {
        private ClientWebSocket ws = new ClientWebSocket();  // WebSocket for communication
        private RTCPeerConnection pc;
        private string wsUrl = "ws://your.websocket.url";  // Replace with actual WebSocket URL
        private ConcurrentDictionary<int, ClientWebSocket> CameraWebsockets = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ClientWebSocket>();

        public async Task Main(CancellationToken token)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Starting WebRTC connection setup.");
            await StartSocket(token);
            await EstablishConnection(token);
            await SendOfferWithCandidates(token);
            _ = Task.Run(() => ReceiveMessages(token));
            Debug.WriteLine("WebRTC connection setup complete.");
        }

        public async Task StartSocket(CancellationToken token)
        {
            if (ws.State != WebSocketState.Open)
            {
                ws = new ClientWebSocket();
                await ws.ConnectAsync(new Uri(wsUrl), token);
                CameraWebsockets[0] = ws;
                Debug.WriteLine("WebSocket connected.");
            }
        }

        public async Task EstablishConnection(CancellationToken token)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Establishing PeerConnection.");
            pc = new RTCPeerConnection();

            // Log ICE connection state changes
            pc.oniceconnectionstatechange += (state) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"ICE connection state changed to: {state}");
            };
            pc.onconnectionstatechange += (state) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Connection state changed to {state}");
            };

            // Initialize a dummy video source
            var testPatternSource = new VideoTestPatternSource(new VpxVideoEncoder());
            MediaStreamTrack videoTrack = new MediaStreamTrack(testPatternSource.GetVideoSourceFormats(), MediaStreamStatusEnum.SendRecv);
            pc.addTrack(videoTrack);
            Debug.WriteLine("Video track added to PeerConnection.");
        }

        public async Task SendOfferWithCandidates(CancellationToken token)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Creating SDP offer.");
            var offer = pc.createOffer();
            await pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
            Debug.WriteLine($"SDP Offer created:\n{offer.sdp}");

            var offerMessage = new
            {
                sdp = offer.sdp,
                type = "offer"
            };
            await SendMessage(offerMessage, token);
            Debug.WriteLine("SDP Offer sent to server.");

            pc.onicecandidate += async (RTCIceCandidate candidate) =>
            {
                if (candidate != null)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine($"ICE candidate gathered:\n{candidate}");
                    var candidateMessage = new { command = "Ice_Candidate", candidate };
                    await SendMessage(candidateMessage, token);
                    Debug.WriteLine("ICE candidate sent to server.");
                }
            };
        }

        private async Task SendMessage(object message, CancellationToken token)
        {
            var ws = CameraWebsockets[0];
            var messageJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
            var messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messageJson);
            await ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(messageBytes), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, token);
            Debug.WriteLine($"Message sent: {messageJson}");
        }

        public async Task ReceiveMessages(CancellationToken token)
        {
            var ws = CameraWebsockets[0];
            var buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[8192]);

            while (ws.State == WebSocketState.Open && !token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                var result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(buffer, token);
                string response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count);
                var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(response);
                Debug.WriteLine($"Received message from server: {response}");

                // Handle SDP Answer
                if (jsonResponse.ContainsKey("sdp"))
                {
                    var sdpAnswer = jsonResponse["sdp"].ToString();
                    var sdpType = jsonResponse["type"].ToString();
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Received SDP Answer:\n{sdpAnswer}");
                    var sdp = SDP.ParseSDPDescription(sdpAnswer);
                    pc.SetRemoteDescription(sdpType == "answer" ? SdpType.answer : SdpType.offer, sdp);
                    Debug.WriteLine("SDP Answer set on PeerConnection.");
                }
                // Handle ICE Candidates
                else if (jsonResponse.ContainsKey("candidate"))
                {
                    var candidate = jsonResponse["candidate"].ToString();
                    Debug.WriteLine($"Received ICE Candidate:\n{candidate}");
                    var iceCandidate = new RTCIceCandidateInit { candidate = candidate };
                    pc.addIceCandidate(iceCandidate);
                    Debug.WriteLine("ICE Candidate added to PeerConnection.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Server Code:
from fastapi import APIRouter, WebSocket
import json
import asyncio
import logging
from starlette.websockets import WebSocketDisconnect
from aiortc import VideoStreamTrack, RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription, RTCIceCandidate
from aiortc.mediastreams import VideoFrame
from fractions import Fraction
import time
import numpy as np

logger = logging.getLogger("uvicorn")

class SyntheticVideoTrack(VideoStreamTrack):
    def __init__(self, fps=15, width=1280, height=720, color=(0, 255, 0)):
        super().__init__()
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.fps = fps
        self.color = color  # RGB color for the synthetic frame background
        self.frame_interval = 1.0 / fps
        self.start_time = time.time()  # Track the start time for PTS calculation

    async def recv(self):
        """Generate synthetic frames at a consistent frame rate."""
        await asyncio.sleep(self.frame_interval)

        # Create a solid color frame
        frame_data = np.full((self.height, self.width, 3), self.color, dtype=np.uint8)
        video_frame = VideoFrame.from_ndarray(frame_data, format="rgb24")

        # Set presentation timestamp (PTS) and time base
        elapsed_time = time.time() - self.start_time
        video_frame.pts = int(elapsed_time * 90000)  # PTS in 90kHz clock
        video_frame.time_base = Fraction(1, 90000)

        return video_frame


class VideoProcessor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.pc = None  # Peer connection

    async def websocket_control(self, websocket: WebSocket):
        logger.info("WebSocket Server Started")

        while True:
            try:
                data = await websocket.receive_text()
                message = json.loads(data)
                logger.info(f"Received message: {message}")

                if message["command"] == "Start_Stream":
                    camera_url = message.get("camera_url")
                    if camera_url:
                        logger.info(f"Starting WebRTC stream with camera URL: {camera_url}")
                        await self.start_webrtc_stream(websocket, camera_url)
                    else:
                        logger.error("No camera URL provided. Cannot start stream.")
                elif message["command"] == "Ice_Candidate":  # Handle ICE candidates
                    logger.info("Received ICE candidate from client")
                    if self.pc is not None:  # Ensure pc is initialized
                        # Extract the full candidate object from the received message
                        candidate_data = message.get("candidate")
                        logger.info(candidate_data)
                        ice_candidate = RTCIceCandidate(
                            foundation=candidate_data.get('foundation'),
                            component=candidate_data.get('component'),
                            priority=candidate_data.get('priority'),
                            ip=candidate_data.get('address'),
                            port=candidate_data.get('port'),
                            type=candidate_data.get('type'),
                            protocol=candidate_data.get('protocol'),
                            sdpMid=candidate_data.get('sdpMid'),
                            sdpMLineIndex=candidate_data.get('sdpMLineIndex')
                        )

                        # Add the ICE candidate to the peer connection
                        await self.pc.addIceCandidate(ice_candidate)
                        logger.info(f"ICE candidate added: {ice_candidate}")
                    else:
                        logger.error("Peer connection not initialized; cannot add ICE candidate.")

            except WebSocketDisconnect as e:
                logger.info(f"WebSocket disconnected: {e}")
                break

    async def start_webrtc_stream(self, websocket, camera_url):
        logger.info("Initializing WebRTC stream")
        
        # Receive offer from client
        offer = await websocket.receive_text()
        logger.info(f"Raw offer received from client: {offer}")

        # Parse the offer
        offer = json.loads(offer)

        # Proceed with WebRTC setup
        self.pc = RTCPeerConnection()

        @self.pc.on("icegatheringstatechange")
        async def on_icegatheringstatechange():
            logger.info(f"ICE gathering state: {self.pc.iceGatheringState}")

        @self.pc.on("iceconnectionstatechange")
        async def on_iceconnectionstatechange():
            logger.info(f"ICE connection state: {self.pc.iceConnectionState}")
            
        # Set up video track using the camera URL
        player = SyntheticVideoTrack(fps=15, width=1280, height=720, color=(0, 0, 255))  # Blue frames
        logger.info(f"Adding camera video track to peer connection: {camera_url}")
        self.pc.addTrack(player)

        # Set remote description using the client's SDP offer
        offer_sdp = RTCSessionDescription(sdp=offer["sdp"], type=offer["type"])
        await self.pc.setRemoteDescription(offer_sdp)

        # Create answer and set local description
        answer = await self.pc.createAnswer()
        await self.pc.setLocalDescription(answer)
        logger.info(f"SDP Answer from server:\n{self.pc.localDescription.sdp}")
        
        # Send SDP answer back to client
        await websocket.send_text(json.dumps({
            "sdp": self.pc.localDescription.sdp,
            "type": self.pc.localDescription.type
        }))
        logger.info("SDP answer sent to client successfully.")

    async def shutdown_webrtc(self):
        if self.pc:
            await self.pc.close()
            self.pc = None
        logger.info("WebRTC connection closed")

# FastAPI router setup
ip_camera_route = APIRouter()
processor = VideoProcessor()

@ip_camera_route.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    await asyncio.create_task(processor.websocket_control(websocket))

Problem Details

The server receives the client’s SDP offer and ICE candidates, responds with an SDP answer and ICE candidates.
The client processes the SDP answer and shows the ICE connection state changing to connected.
Shortly after, the client’s connection state changes to closed and then failed.
On the server side, it logs "Consent to send expired" after showing an ICE connection state of completed.

Reproduced Output and Logs
Server Logs:
INFO:     Adding camera video track to peer connection: http://129.125.136.20/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?camera=1
INFO:     ICE gathering state: gathering
INFO:     ICE gathering state: complete
INFO:     SDP Answer from server:
v=0
o=- 3938952277 3938952277 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=video 58160 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 100
c=IN IP4 172.18.0.2
a=sendrecv
a=mid:0
a=msid:20030b46-dcd7-402e-91a9-61acc96fc861 0526e15c-fb87-49ec-a372-9d752dbe5f46
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-mux
a=ssrc:2884284437 cname:f6435a48-f40f-4fbc-8ac2-5833d73158f4
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=candidate:2042d42f166ed704ca002a0751b390c3 1 udp 2130706431 172.18.0.2 58160 typ host
a=candidate:b0d9b1b22e9ac473e83e963403e57c55 1 udp 1694498815 37.228.203.142 27206 typ srflx raddr 172.18.0.2 rport 58160
a=end-of-candidates
a=ice-ufrag:9GzX
a=ice-pwd:6ErYyxnwubAqbQOsEEf8np
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D6:D6:BE:00:51:1E:B4:DB:90:4C:EC:63:BC:00:E0:27:3E:97:1F:A2:61:10:8D:AB:5C:7D:CE:4D:8A:5A:03:79
a=setup:active
INFO:     SDP answer sent to client successfully.
INFO:     Received message: {'command': 'Ice_Candidate', 'candidate': {'IceServer': None, 'candidate': '3168018052 1 udp 2113937663 192.168.0.82 53352 typ host generation 0', 'sdpMid': None, 'sdpMLineIndex': 0, 'foundation': '3168018052', 'component': 1, 'priority': 2113937663, 'address': '192.168.0.82', 'protocol': 0, 'port': 53352, 'type': 0, 'tcpType': 0, 'relatedAddress': None, 'relatedPort': 0, 'usernameFragment': 'RRVM', 'DestinationEndPoint': None}}
INFO:     Received ICE candidate from client
INFO:     {'IceServer': None, 'candidate': '3168018052 1 udp 2113937663 192.168.0.82 53352 typ host generation 0', 'sdpMid': None, 'sdpMLineIndex': 0, 'foundation': '3168018052', 'component': 1, 'priority': 2113937663, 'address': '192.168.0.82', 'protocol': 0, 'port': 53352, 'type': 0, 'tcpType': 0, 'relatedAddress': None, 'relatedPort': 0, 'usernameFragment': 'RRVM', 'DestinationEndPoint': None}
INFO:     ICE candidate added: RTCIceCandidate(component=1, foundation='3168018052', ip='192.168.0.82', port=53352, priority=2113937663, protocol=0, type=0, relatedAddress=None, relatedPort=None, sdpMid=None, sdpMLineIndex=0, tcpType=None)
INFO:     Connection(3) Check CandidatePair(('172.18.0.2', 58160) -> ('192.168.0.82', 53352)) State.FROZEN -> State.WAITING
INFO:     ICE connection state: checking
INFO:     Connection(3) Check CandidatePair(('172.18.0.2', 58160) -> ('192.168.0.82', 53352)) State.WAITING -> State.IN_PROGRESS
INFO:     Connection(3) Check CandidatePair(('172.18.0.2', 58160) -> ('192.168.0.82', 53352)) State.IN_PROGRESS -> State.SUCCEEDED
INFO:     Connection(3) ICE completed
INFO:     ICE connection state: completed
INFO:     Connection(3) Consent to send expired
INFO:     ICE connection state: failed

Client Logs:
Video track added to PeerConnection.
Creating SDP offer.
SDP Offer created:
v=0
o=- 42541 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=sipsorcery
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVP 96 100
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:RRVM
a=ice-pwd:LJSKIMKDKLTSBQVKWDUMSJFN
a=fingerprint:sha-256 1A:78:0D:CD:C2:A3:9F:C0:75:0D:87:D4:F9:09:07:66:91:85:E9:C5:06:AB:F1:2F:39:78:F1:DD:BD:6D:75:24
a=setup:actpass
a=candidate:3168018052 1 udp 2113937663 192.168.0.82 53352 typ host generation 0
a=ice-options:ice2,trickle
a=mid:0
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=fmtp:100 packetization-mode=1
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=end-of-candidates
a=sendrecv
a=ssrc:449817168 cname:841fc310-157d-4732-9ab4-39f2f6249f20

Message sent: {"sdp":"v=0\r\no=- 42541 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1\r\ns=sipsorcery\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\nm=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVP 96 100\r\nc=IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=ice-ufrag:RRVM\r\na=ice-pwd:LJSKIMKDKLTSBQVKWDUMSJFN\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 1A:78:0D:CD:C2:A3:9F:C0:75:0D:87:D4:F9:09:07:66:91:85:E9:C5:06:AB:F1:2F:39:78:F1:DD:BD:6D:75:24\r\na=setup:actpass\r\na=candidate:3168018052 1 udp 2113937663 192.168.0.82 53352 typ host generation 0\r\na=ice-options:ice2,trickle\r\na=mid:0\r\na=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb\r\na=rtpmap:100 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=fmtp:100 packetization-mode=1\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=end-of-candidates\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=ssrc:449817168 cname:841fc310-157d-4732-9ab4-39f2f6249f20\r\n","type":"offer"}
SDP Offer sent to server.
ICE candidate gathered:
3168018052 1 udp 2113937663 192.168.0.82 53352 typ host generation 0
Message sent: {"command":"Ice_Candidate","candidate":{"IceServer":null,"candidate":"3168018052 1 udp 2113937663 192.168.0.82 53352 typ host generation 0","sdpMid":null,"sdpMLineIndex":0,"foundation":"3168018052","component":1,"priority":2113937663,"address":"192.168.0.82","protocol":0,"port":53352,"type":0,"tcpType":0,"relatedAddress":null,"relatedPort":0,"usernameFragment":"RRVM","DestinationEndPoint":null}}
ICE candidate sent to server.
WebRTC connection setup complete.
Received message from server: {"sdp": "v=0\r\no=- 3938952277 3938952277 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\ns=-\r\nt=0 0\r\na=group:BUNDLE 0\r\na=msid-semantic:WMS *\r\nm=video 58160 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 100\r\nc=IN IP4 172.18.0.2\r\na=sendrecv\r\na=mid:0\r\na=msid:20030b46-dcd7-402e-91a9-61acc96fc861 0526e15c-fb87-49ec-a372-9d752dbe5f46\r\na=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0\r\na=rtcp-mux\r\na=ssrc:2884284437 cname:f6435a48-f40f-4fbc-8ac2-5833d73158f4\r\na=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb\r\na=rtpmap:100 H264/90000\r\na=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb\r\na=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f\r\na=candidate:2042d42f166ed704ca002a0751b390c3 1 udp 2130706431 172.18.0.2 58160 typ host\r\na=candidate:b0d9b1b22e9ac473e83e963403e57c55 1 udp 1694498815 37.228.203.142 27206 typ srflx raddr 172.18.0.2 rport 58160\r\na=end-of-candidates\r\na=ice-ufrag:9GzX\r\na=ice-pwd:6ErYyxnwubAqbQOsEEf8np\r\na=fingerprint:sha-256 D6:D6:BE:00:51:1E:B4:DB:90:4C:EC:63:BC:00:E0:27:3E:97:1F:A2:61:10:8D:AB:5C:7D:CE:4D:8A:5A:03:79\r\na=setup:active\r\n", "type": "answer"}
Received SDP Answer:
v=0
o=- 3938952277 3938952277 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=msid-semantic:WMS *
m=video 58160 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 96 100
c=IN IP4 172.18.0.2
a=sendrecv
a=mid:0
a=msid:20030b46-dcd7-402e-91a9-61acc96fc861 0526e15c-fb87-49ec-a372-9d752dbe5f46
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-mux
a=ssrc:2884284437 cname:f6435a48-f40f-4fbc-8ac2-5833d73158f4
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42e01f
a=candidate:2042d42f166ed704ca002a0751b390c3 1 udp 2130706431 172.18.0.2 58160 typ host
a=candidate:b0d9b1b22e9ac473e83e963403e57c55 1 udp 1694498815 37.228.203.142 27206 typ srflx raddr 172.18.0.2 rport 58160
a=end-of-candidates
a=ice-ufrag:9GzX
a=ice-pwd:6ErYyxnwubAqbQOsEEf8np
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D6:D6:BE:00:51:1E:B4:DB:90:4C:EC:63:BC:00:E0:27:3E:97:1F:A2:61:10:8D:AB:5C:7D:CE:4D:8A:5A:03:79
a=setup:active

ICE connection state changed to: checking
SDP Answer set on PeerConnection.
ICE connection state changed to: connected
Connection state changed to connecting
Connection state changed to closed
Connection state changed to failed


The ICE candidates and SDP exchange appear to be successful. However, the client’s connection state changes to failed shortly after switching to connected.
The server logs "Consent to send expired" immediately after reporting ICE connection state: completed.

Is there a step we're missing to maintain the connection or an issue with the ICE configuration? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!
